# React-native : Error reading bundle /User/..../main.jsbundle

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bundle

When I run my application with "npm run ios"
Here is the error that appears:

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4AUP.png)

Do you have an idea ?
Everything worked fine at launch on xcode then without any changes I first had the error "no bundle url present" then this one ...

I have tried solutions from different forums but nothing helps

thanks a lot for your help